# How to clr/c# parameters

Tags: c#, parameters, clr

I have a C# library with a function defined as

```
public partial class YuniqueInterface
{
    public struct MaterialTypeInformation
    {
        public string materialDescription;
        public string materialType;
        public string materialActive;
    }

    public bool GetMaterialTypes(List<MaterialTypeInformation> materialTypeInfo)
```

Now from clr/c++ code how would I call this function?

I've read enough info to drive me crazy and just not getting it.
Thanks

Comment: Are you able to modify the source code of the C# library?

Comment: Yes, I'm able to modify or request changes.